# What is the best way to pass multiply parameters as one http query parameter?

Tags: java, http, url, oauth, salesforce

I have java web application (servlet) that does user authentication using SalesForce [Server OAuth Authentication Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm). This OAuth Authentication provides "state" query parameter to pass any data on callback. I have a bunch of parameters that I want to pass through this "state" query param. What is the best way to do it? In java in particularly?

Or in other words, what is the best way to pass an array or map as a single http query parameter?

Comment: You might consider encoding it in JSON, and then encoding the JSON string using Base64.  This keeps most people from monkeying with your parameters, and is very resilient when passing through OAuth etc...

Comment: Thanks, @Jamie, I have done it this way, seems like working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all in json or xml format or any other format and then encode in base64 as a one large string. Take care that params can impose some hard limit on some browser/web server.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel Luyo, I have done it this way, seems like working solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have done it this way. Thank you guys! Here are some code snippets to illustrate how it works for me:

```
    // forming state query parameter
    Map<String, String> stateMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    stateMap.put("1", "111");
    stateMap.put("2", "222");
    stateMap.put("3", "333");

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stateMap);
    String stateJSON = jsonObject.toString();

    System.out.println("stateJSON: " + stateJSON);

    String stateQueryParam = Base64.encodeBase64String(stateJSON.getBytes());

    System.out.println("stateQueryParam: " + stateQueryParam);

    // getting map from state query param
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    stateMap = objectMapper.readValue(Base64.decodeBase64(stateQueryParam.getBytes()), LinkedHashMap.class);

    System.out.println("stateMap: " + stateMap);
```

Here is output:

```
stateJSON: {"1":"111","2":"222","3":"333"}
stateQueryParam: eyIxIjoiMTExIiwiMiI6IjIyMiIsIjMiOiIzMzMifQ==

stateMap: {1=111, 2=222, 3=333}
```